# Access to /Apps/ folder for iOS developers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a possible project which involves accessing the /Apps/ subfolder in iOS. My question is : Is it possible for developers to access the /Apps/ folder information and if yes can they rewrite a file inside another app (rewrite for ex. the app icon of another app). I am talking about rewriting files that would not interfere in any way with the work of the other app.

I'm asking if this is possible for legitimate application which would be submitted to the App Store.

The best example I can think of is the TapJoy network which is for incentivizing app downloads. They are able to detect whether you have downloaded a certain app and if you have played it even.

Thank You

Comment: You can retrieve the contents of your app's sandbox folder (much different than rewriting in other folders) through Xcode, but nothing else.

Comment: I believe Apple no longer allows incentivizing app downloads. Your app would be rejected because of that anyway.

Comment: I know they do not allow incentivized downloads anymore and the project I am consulting on is not for that. I just gave TapJoy as an example since I didn't know they use their own api for that. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to access any file or folder outside of your own app's sandbox. This is a technical restriction that you can only get around on a jailbroken device. Also, if you managed to find some way to circumvent this then your app would be pulled from the App Store.

TapJoy works by having app developers participate and integrate their API. Apps that integrate TapJoy inform TapJoy's server when they are run.

Answer (score 4):

Even if this were possible it would NEVER be accepted into the app store.

> rewriting files that would not interfere in any way with the work of
>   the other app

...as the owner of an App development company, I consider EVERY file within our apps essential to the correct operation of them, whether that be functional operation or branding, even changing an image or icon dilutes the message the original developer intended. Bad bad bad.

Comment: Well said! I'd also like to add that only the developer of an App knows which file is used and can be changed and in which ways. Simply trying to change a file and if it works one time saying "yup, works just fine" isn't enough.

Comment: I guess the OP didn't think it was well said however! :)

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I appreciate the answer and learned a few new things from both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't any rewrite of another app break its digital signature (and thus prevent it from running)? So that's another reason the answer is NO.